# Requirement to upload new version application on Google Play

Tags: android

I am new to android developing.

I published my company's first application with version 1.0 on Google play. That time, I din't know the importance of signed key.

I have just developed second application and want to publish it. But I don't know password of signed key. So First of all, what changed I need to do in manifest file. And I want to keep same package name as it was before.

What to do for that ? Please help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload an update with the same package name you must sign the apk with the same key as the version that it is replacing.

If you cannot do this, you need to upload a completely new app with a new package name.

Comment: But I don't remember the password of the previous signed key. So is there anyway by which I can get password ???

Comment: I don't think so, maybe you should try to connect with the google support. They may suggest some solution for you.

Comment: Ohk, thank you. And does google notifies users about new version itself or we need to do some coding ??? I am using C2D. and send notification to user from asp.net website.

Comment: Google will not help you. There is nothing they can do. If you do not know the password, you need to create a new app. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: it will hurt nobody to ask them anyway :)